# What's the difference between a cyclic and periodic function?

Tags: definition, periodic-functions

I've seen the words "cyclic" and "periodic" used to describe characteristics of a given function. What do they mean? I can't seem to find a difference. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function) says a periodic function is one that repeats values in a periodic interval.

Maybe I was mistaking about the phrase "cyclic" being used to describe functions. One place I do see the word used in math is [cyclic group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group).

Comment: Can you give an example of where you saw a function described as "cyclic"?

Comment: @Rahul I think I first came across the term when reading about integer factorization algorithms. I found a mention of it here http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cyclic%20function

Comment: Your link gives me "To view the definition of *cyclic function*, activate your Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary FREE TRIAL now!" Can you just quote the example in your question? Although I'm guessing Greg's answer is probably what you need.

Comment: "a mathematical function that changes in value by an additive constant whenever its variable arguments pass continuously through a cycle of values"

Answer (score 3):

A cyclic function might be referring to the iterates of a function (that is, when it's composed with itself multiple times). In particular, a function might be called cyclic if one of its iterates is the identity function. For example, every permutation of a finite set is a cyclic function according to [this definition](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/41012).

In particular, this is a completely different notion from a function being periodic, which discusses only the function itself (not its iterates) and how it behaves under translations of the domain.

Comment: Can you update the link? It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that cyclic just means that it has certain range of independent values it can only use. For example, a Lagrangian becomes cyclic when you convert into polar coordinates. Essentially, the only values that are  going to happen/actually have an effect on the dependent variable are [O,2pi] Therefore it is cyclic. I guess functions in polar coordinates in general might be an easy example of cyclic functions?

[This info on Lagrangians being cyclic in polar came from Thornton's Classical Dynamics 5th]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and welcome to math.SE! One small advice: the answer could be more close to the question: what is the difference between cyclic v.s. periodic. Thus better to compare the two, instead of just stating one.

Answer (score -1):

The difference between a cyclic and periodic function is that one is the inverse of the other.

Take $f=\sin(x)$, which is periodic. An inverse $f^{-1}$ is normally done after restricting the domain of $f$ so that it's one-to-one and $f^{-1}$ isn't multi-valued. This does not interest us.

If you don't restrict the domain, $f^{-1}$ becomes multi-valued and we call it cyclic.

And if you invert a cyclic function you get a periodic function.